# Img and text in the same line in div

Tags: html, css

I try to make envelope img to be in the same line as text on the right side:

http://codepen.io/tulpa/pen/ZLvqmE

```
.ico{
float:left;
margin-right: 5px;
vertical-align: middle;
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

you should use `flex-basis` in flex divs so that they have same label.

Answer (score 0):

Use `display: inline-block` rather than floating your image.

```
.ico{
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: 5px;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`Float` and `vertical-align` do not go along (see `.ico{}` rules).

`display:block` and `vertical-align` do not go along (see `img{}` rules ).

**You need to reset `float` and `display` for `.ico`.**

`vertical-align` can be tuned *(you should read/look for the [specification](https://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Properties/vertical-align))* :

```css
img.ico {
  float: none;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 5px;
  vertical-align: -0.6em;/* or middle but you can tune this with any decimal value */
}

div {
  font-style: normal;
  font-family: sans-serif, Arial;
}

img {
  width: auto;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  display: block;
}

#con {
  background-color: #00ff14;
  justify-content: center;
}

#logo {
  background-color: #ff8900;
}

#menu {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-around;
  margin: auto;
  border-color: red;
  border-width: 0px;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

#tresc {
  margin: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
  height: 100%;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  text-align: justify;
  text-justify: inter-word;
  justify-content: center;
  border-color: red;
  border-width: 1px;
  border: solid;
}

#stopka {
  background-color: gainsboro;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

#m1 {
  border-bottom: solid;
  border-top: solid;
  border-width: 2px;
  padding: 4px;
  border-color: greenyellow;
  -webkit-transition: border-color 1s;
}

#m1:hover {
  border-bottom: solid;
  border-top: solid;
  border-width: 2px;
  padding: 4px;
  border-color: red;
}

#tekst {
  line-height: 3px;
}
```

```html
<div id="stopka">
  <div class="m3"><img src="https://sinshop.pl/upload/sinshop/allegro/envelope.png" class="ico"><span id="tekst">KONTAKT</span></div>
  <div class="m3"><img src="https://sinshop.pl/upload/sinshop/allegro/envelope.png" class="ico">WYSYŁKA</div>
  <div class="m3"><img src="https://sinshop.pl/upload/sinshop/allegro/envelope.png" class="ico">REGULAMIN</div>
  <div class="m3"><img src="https://sinshop.pl/upload/sinshop/allegro/envelope.png" class="ico">PŁATNOŚCI</div>
</div>
```

I also turned  `<div id="m3">` into  `<div class="m3">` .**`Id` can be used only once per page**.